# Git fails to clone or pull with SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to `clone` (or `pull` latest changes from) an existing repository on `github`. It worked on Windows 7 without any problem. Then I upgraded to Windows 10, and had to re-install git. Ever since I'm getting this error when I try to `clone` and existing repository or `pull` changes:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/...': OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to github.com:443
```

I've searched online, but haven't found a definite resolution to this yet. I'm trying this from my work machine, so maybe that's contributing to the issue (I should probably try on my personal computer also). But any definite advice on resolving this is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The issue comes from when git is downloading objects, the github server resets the connection due to maybe a network failure or disconnection, just use another connection and it will work Ok.

I have not gone into the technical details but that should solve the problem.